# Sql Select Statement with Paging c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, select, pagination

What is the correct way of writing a select statment on c# controller for paging. This is the best I came up with, but I know it doesn't work because it's showing all data on my first page on the grid... please help

```
public JsonResult getData(int start, int limit)
{
  List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
  using (SqlConnection con = new       SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices1"].ConnectionString))
 {
 SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT State, Capital FROM MYDBTABLE";
 con.Open();
 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
   MyItem item = new MyItem();
   item.State = reader[0].ToString(); 
   item.Capital = reader[1].ToString(); 
   items.Add(item);
 }
 con.Close();

 if ((start + limit) > Myitem.Count)
 {
    limit = Myitem.Count - start;
 }
 return Json(new {  myTable = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use limit keyword in query?

Comment: I am sorry mserioli.. I am totally new to this... could you please show me an example...

Comment: Please see [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/) and read through [all of the comments](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx).

Comment: Hi Aaron... m using sql 2008... is it same

Comment: Yes, the article I pointed out was written for SQL Server 2005 but it is still applicable to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks Aaron... I am going over it right now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the template for stored procs that I like to use for paging.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcName] 
    @page_size INT
    , @page_num INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ; WITH RESULTS AS
    (
        SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <order_col> DESC) AS rn
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <order_col> ASC) AS rn_reversed
        FROM <table>
    )
    SELECT *
        , CAST(rn + rn_reversed - 1 AS INT) AS total_rows
        , CAST(CASE (rn + rn_reversed - 1) % @page_size
            WHEN 0 THEN (rn + rn_reversed - 1) / @page_size
            ELSE ((rn + rn_reversed - 1) / @page_size) + 1 
            END AS INT) AS total_pages
    FROM RESULTS a
    WHERE a.rn BETWEEN 1 + ((@page_num - 1) * @page_size) AND @page_num * @page_size
    ORDER BY rn ASC 

END
```

You just need to pass in `page_size` and `page_num` to the stored proc and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you Norla... M trying to implement this... but is page_size the same as "start"... I pass these parameters from my store on extjs, where it is set as start: 0 and limit: 20...

Comment: @EagleFox page_size is limit (20) and page_num should start at 1 and increment by 1.

Comment: I see... which shouldn't be a problem because extjs params send that automaticallly... but I have always seen start is set at 0 on almost all the extjs examples... let me try both and will see how it goes.. thank you Norla

Comment: @EagleFox Right, extjs...  If you're absolutely stuck with those two params you can edit the WHERE clause to compensate.  Lemme know if you need a hand with that one.

Comment: That'll be awesome Norla... thanks... I am almost done changing it to my code

Comment: Hi Norla... my grid displays 20 records and shows page 1... I can click next page and the toolbar shows page 2 but the grid has data from page 1... is the start and limit passed from the controller or from extjs grid store

Comment: Oh man, this is where it gets complicated.  I'm using Ext.net (http://ext.net/), a .Net wrapper for extjs, and I had to manually program the paging toolbar with handlers for every button click.  You may want to close this question and start a new one so you can gear it toward extjs.

Comment: There is a problem with how the total_rows and total_pages are calculated. Seems to be due to the rn_reversed. Take a look at the numbers it produces...

Comment: <order_col> what is it ? what if i have multiple asc and desc how that will reflect on your code ?
can i just pass table name as parameter and how ?
thanks

Comment: @Al-HanashMoataz You can define the "rn" field with any asc/desc combinations, as long as "rn_reversed" has the exact opposite.  E.g. col1 ASC, col2 DESC, col3 ASC for the former, then col1 DESC, col2 ASC, col3 DESC for the latter.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq and use `Skip()` and `Take()` like this:

```
public JsonResult getData(int page, int limit)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices1"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT State, Capital FROM MYDBTABLE";
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    int start = (page * limit) - limit;
    List<MyItem> items  = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                           select new MyItem
                           {
                                State = row["State"].ToString(),
                                Capital = row["Capital"].ToString()
                           }).Skip(start - 1).Take(limit).ToList();
    return Json(new {  myTable = items }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Dang... thanks Jack Hughes... I didn't know it could be done without stored procedure

Comment: same problem exists with this way too.. I can get the first page with 20 records but it does not show the 2nd page data, even though the toolbar says page 2... any idea why it would do that Jack?

Comment: Weird, not sure why that didn't work. I made a small modification to the code, instead of start being the row position I changed it to use the page number.

Answer (score 0):

The basic template I use is:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER(), <Rest of your columns>
FROM <Your Tables/Joins>
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() >= (@PageNum * @RowsPerPage)
AND ROW_NUMBER() < (@PageNum+1 * @RowsPerPage)
```

Comment: Thanks KeithS... is this directly on the controller or on the stored procedure

Comment: You can create a stored procedure using a query like this, then execute it passing the parameters, or you can send it directly to the server with a SqlCommand. If you're using "vanilla" ADO.NET, as you seem to be, I recommend stored procs. If I were doing this, I'd set up a Linq provider, like Entity Framework; then the query goes into compiler-checked code and becomes something like `MyDbContext.Query<MyResultObject>().Select(r=>r).Skip(PageNum * PerPage).Take(PerPage).ToList()`;

Comment: I am sorry KeithS.. I am not using Entity Framework... I am using extjs 4.1.. basically with a grid paging toolbar. I am having hard time getting the paged data from db

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` is missing `OVER()`. Besides, you cannot use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` or any other ranking function in a predicate. You'll have to create a derived table where `ROW_NUMBER()` is calculated first: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/10044